# How do I backup everything on "Photos" icon on my iPhone locally

Tags: iphone, backup, photos

"Photos" icon/app on my iPhone has different types of media photos and videos let alone different formats like burst and live.
Importing them to a PC in order to save them locally converts live images to still and I am not even sure about the burst.

Is there a method to save them locally? I am aware on iTunes backup but I want to backup only the contents of the "Photos" not the entire phone also the iTunes backups aren't viewable.

Comment: Windows cannot handle Live Pictures at all. It can only recognise them as 2 identical file names, one with. jpg or .heic, the other with .mov. I've never tested burst mode - you will probably get individual pictures.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be asking two questions: 1) How to get the contents of your iPhone Photos library on your PC in a viewable format, 2) How to transfer special format media.

1. **Backup photos on PC**: [Set up iCloud on your PC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205323), so that whatever is in your iPhone Photos library can also be seen via iCloud.com on the PC. Note that iCloud is a syncing service, not a backup (Deleting photos from one device will also delete them from other devices). So if you want a backup, you should download items from iCloud into regular folders on your PC that you can click open and view.

There are also other ways, but this is the most straightforward.

2. **Special format media**: Live photos, bursts etc. only work within the Apple ecosystem. You can convert Live Photos into videos, then download on PC. To do this, open Photos > select Live photo > tap the Share button at bottom left > select 'Save as video' option. Bursts are intended to let you choose the best photo(s) and discard the rest. If you want to keep more than one or all of a burst sequence, open Photos > select Burst photo > tap each frame you want to keep > Done.

Answer (score -2):

Try AirDrop or Digital Pictures

Comment: AirDrop to where?